# Spring Data JPA "OR" with single parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Is it possible to have a Spring Data JPA repository method like this:

```
User findByEmailOrUserName(String usernameOrEmail);
```

The above method name doesn't work as Spring Data JPA throws an exception when it tries to find the second parameter that needs to be bound to second property name in the method.

I want a method name that will translate to `select t from User t where t.email = :usernameOrEmail OR t.userName = :usernameOrEmail`

Does the method name queries have such a possibility?

Comment: well, not very elegant, but you can get the same result by defining the repo method to take two params `User findByEmailOrUserName(String email, String userName);`, and then the caller can pass the same param twice: `findByEmailOrUserName("mubin", "mubin")` or `findByEmailOrUserName("mubin@so.com", "mubin@so.com")`. This way other caller can actually call it with different params if needed. Still, not sure passing duplicate params is a good idea.

Comment: @Nicolau Thanks, but that doesn't answer the question. I am not using Spring DATA REST

Comment: @Nicolau Please re-read my question. I was asking for method-name queries. None of your answer satisfies my criteria.

Comment: @Nicolau That is what I said in my answer as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With current latest version of Spring Data JPA (v1.10.2), this is not possible. I don't see any such requests for future versions either.

Answer (score 2):

[Using @Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query):

```
@Query("select t from User t where t.email = ?1 OR t.userName = ?1")
User findByEmailOrUserName(String usernameOrEmail);
```

By default, [Spring Data JPA](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) uses position-based parameter binding.

---

**Also**, you can use [Named Parameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters) to give a method parameter a concrete name and bind the name in the query:

```
@Query("select t from User t where t.email = :usernameOrEmail OR t.userName = :usernameOrEmail")
User findByEmailOrUserName(@Param("usernameOrEmail") String usernameOrEmail);
```

---

**As a workaround**, if you are using [Spring Data REST](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) and your interest is just to send a single http parameter in the request, you can use `@Param` to link the same http parameter to both parameter in the repository's method and this does the trick without needing `@Query`:

```
User findByEmailOrUserName(
        @Param("usernameOrEmail") String email, 
        @Param("usernameOrEmail") String username);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 and later there's actually a workaround for this, your repo could look like:

```
    User findByEmailOrUserName(String username, String email);

    default User findByEmailOrUserName(String usernameOrEmail) {
        return findByEmailOrUserName(usernameOrEmail, usernameOrEmail);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**suppose in yours service layer youhave one method like**

*In service:*

```
@Autowired(required = true)
private IUserRepository idao;

User getByNameOrMail(String name,String email)
{
 idao.findByuserNameOremail(name,email)
}
```

*In repository:*

```
User findByuserNameOremail(String name,String email);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, you need to write a repository method for two parameters and call this method with the same value for two parameters. You dont need to write explicit SQL commands.

Your **repository interface** should be implemented like this;

```
User findByEmailOrUserName(String email, String username);
```

And your **service method** calling repository should be ;

```
public User getUserByEmailOrUsername(String usernameOrEmail) {
    return repository.findByEmailOrUserName(usernameOrEmail, usernameOrEmail);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

yes we can use Or for this case but you need to check in User whether the email and username value as same as Email & UserName.for this thing go to the eclipse,spring tool suite what ever **IDE** you are using for coding and in upper in search or quickaccess text box is their,type outline their and open yours pojo class.you will see for property name  *email* & *userName* what are the getters value.

> Ex: getuserName();

Then copy userName only and you can put it

> findByuserNameOremail(String nameOremail);

Like this you have to do based on yours pojo class getters.

Comment: I already mentioned that having only one parameter is not working. Have you tested it yourself?

Comment: with one parameter it won't be possible with two parameter it possible because spring data jpa generates sql queries on behalf of you.

Comment: I know it is possible with two parameters. The whole point of asking this question was to know if it is possible with one parameter or not. Please read the question carefully before answering.