# Spring Data error generating query from method name

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm trying to implement a custom method in my Spring Data JPA repository.

I'm using query generation from method name, and I have something like this:

```
List<Person> findByFirstNameOrLastName(String key);
```

I specified a single parameter for the method because I have a single search key that could match `firstName` or `lastName`, but on application startup I'm getting this application:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': 
        Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

I suppose this error depends on method signature...

So, is there a way to specify a single param for my method using query creation or should I implement custom logic to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49345382/4071001) to see other options around the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Person> findByFirstNameOrLastName(String firstName, String lastName);
```

Yes, it's an issue with the method signature. Spring Data expects 2 parameters when the "or" condition is present in a method name. And you need to pass a `key` value for both parameters.

Alternatively, you could write a `@Query` over the method like:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM person p WHERE p.lastName=:key OR p.firstName =:key")
List<AccountInformation> findByFirstNameOrLastName(@Param("key") String key);
```

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me

```
 List<Person> findByFirstNameOrLastNameAllIgnoreCase(String firstName, String lastName);
```