# What is the Spring Data JPA method to use findBy for multiple fields and also use Containing clause for all the fields

Tags: java, spring, db2, repository, spring-data-jpa

I have a class called Profile and its JPA repository ProfileRepo
I'm trying to use findBy method to find names using first name or middle name or last name and also using containing clause.

```
public class Profile{
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Am using the following query in the JPA repository but it is not accepting the method

```
List<Profile> findByLastNameContainingOrFirstNameContainingOrMiddleNameContainingAllIgnoreCase(String firstName,
        String lastName,String midName);
```

Kindly help out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410660/spring-data-error-generating-query-from-method-name

Comment: Well, there might be a way out of it if you follow the specs correctly and start experimenting with simpler queries first, but doYouReallyThinkItIsSaneToUseSuchALongNameForAMethod instead of just using `@Query`?

Comment: Something like this : @Query("select u from User u where u.firstname = :firstname or u.lastname = :lastname")
  User findByLastnameOrFirstname(@Param("lastname") String lastname,
                                 @Param("firstname") String firstname);

Comment: There is no such "JPA" method. You are referring to "Spring Data JPA" which is not the same as the "JPA API". Tags fixed

Comment: @Peacels I got your point but the issue is I need to use Contains as user can search for Rob for Robert or Robin or I can search ob and still produce the same result..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<Profile> findByFirstNameIgnoreCaseContainingOrLastNameIgnoreCaseContainingOrMidNameIgnoreCaseContaining(String firstName, String lastName, String midName);
```

or this:

```
@Query("select p from Profile p where upper(p.firstName) like concat('%', upper(?1), '%') or upper(p.lastName) like concat('%', upper(?2), '%') or upper(p.midName) like concat('%', upper(?3), '%')")
List<Profile> getByNames(String firstName, String lastName, String midName);
```

Comment: I kinda tried something similar @Query("SELECT p FROM Profile p WHERE p.firstName LIKE CONCAT('%',:name,'%') or p.lastName LIKE CONCAT('%',:name,'%') 
or p.middleName LIKE CONCAT('%',:name,'%')")
 List<Profile> findByName(@Param("name") String input);

Comment: Thanks @Cepr0  the first one actually worked so i avoided writing query.