# search with multiple column in MongoDB, JAVA Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

I tried

```
Page<Session> findBySessionIdOrUserIDContains(String session_id_search_key, String user_id_search_key, Pageable pageable);
```

but not working. I need page response so it will be good if I get correct find query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use exact parameter names in the method name:

```
Page<Session> findBySessionIdOrUserIDContaining(String sessionId, String userId, Pageable pageable); // This means: sessionId equals and userId containing
```

If you want to use both parameter as containing you can use `findBySessionIdContainingOrUserIDContaining` as method name.

[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44411022/what-is-the-spring-data-jpa-method-to-use-findby-for-multiple-fields-and-also-us)

Comment: Thanks Hamed for your time. Let me check. Can you please tell me difference between Contains and Containing.