# Add Two Conditions in JpaRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i am trying to do a POC - using `JpaRepository` filter out the data by adding two conditions.

I have written a code like below

```js
public interface TemplateRepository extends JpaRepository<Template, Long>  {

    List<Template> findByTemplateNameContains(String templateName);//This is Working Fine
    List<Template> findByTemplateNameAndActiveFlagContains(String templateName, String activeFlag);// My POC       
}
```

`templateName` column is a `VARCHAR2` and `activeFlag` is a `Char` in the Oracle Database. I am trying to filter the data with both `templatename`
and `activeFlag`.

I pass the input object in SoapUI app (`POST`) request.

`{
    "netting":"karu_test",
    "activeFlag": "Y"
}`

but I get the below error

> "Parameter value [%Y%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Character (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%Y%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Character (n/a)]"

I understand this error like, the `ACTIVE_FLAG` column is `CHAR(1)` so type mismatch happend. But how to achieve the same functionality  ?

More over .. how to use multiple table joins and condition in `JpaRepository`

I changed the type of `activeFlag` to `Char` still i get the same error.

Template class

```js
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name="TEMPLATE_DEF")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Template {

    @Column(name="TEMPLATE_ID")
    @Id
    private String nettingTemplateId;
    @Column(name="TEMPLATE_NAME")
    private String templateName;
    @Column(name="LAST_UPDATE")
    private Date lastUpdate;
    @Column(name="UPDATE_USER_ID")
    private Integer updUsrId;
    @Column(name="ACTIVE_FLAG")
    private char activeFlag;
    @Column(name="VERSION")
    private Integer Version;
    @Column(name="CREATION_DATE")
    private Date creationDate;
    @Column(name="CREATE_USER_ID")
    private Integer createUsrId;


}
```

Comment: It would be easier if you post the "Template" entity class as well.
Why can't you use "char" for 'activeFlag' if it is a SingleCharacter?

Comment: The type of your method argument has to match the type in the database. As you have a `char` you should use a `char` as argument as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44411022/what-is-the-spring-data-jpa-method-to-use-findby-for-multiple-fields-and-also-us?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your Active flag is a char so no point in putting containing for activeFlag rather do a exact match, change method signature to

```
List<Template> findByTemplateNameContainsAndActiveFlag(String templateName, char activeFlag);// My POC
```

I have tested it it will match name with like and activeFlag based on value of it

Comment: Thanks Shailesh...I will test this and accept your answer. One Question-  for one table , this looks good but how about a query involve more than one table ? Any pointers for the best approach?

Comment: If your Entity is well defined  with proper primary -foreign keys  then it will bring data itself , however in case you want to join multiple tables like bringing data for reports , JPA queries is best suited, read more @ https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below JPA Query

```
List<Template> findByTemplateNameContainingAndActiveFlagContaining(String templateName, Character activeFlag);
```