# Spring Boot Data JPA method for two columns with one entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I try to find a Spring Data JPA method that finds the data from two columns but with one set.

I mean I have a table and I want to use the same set in two `where in` clause.

Now, I use that method: `findAllByCallerInOrCalleeIn(Set<String> callerPhones, Set<String> calleePhones, Pageable pageable);` `callerPhones` and `calleePhones` are exactly the same.

I have tried method names below but they had failed:

```
findAllByCallerInOrCalleeIn(Set<String> phones, Pageable pageable)
findAllByCallerInAndCalleeIn(Set<String> phones, Pageable pageable)
findAllByCallerOrCalleeIn(Set<String> phones, Pageable pageable)
findAllByCallerAndCalleeIn(Set<String> phones, Pageable pageable)
```

Can you give me a suggestion about this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using @Query or putting the same parameter twice,
see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49345382/13310744) answer

Comment: I know @Query but I tried to write a JPA method. Thank you